# OpenVPN HMAC authentication failing despite seemingly identical client & server configs

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I've looked all over for a solution to this, and I can't seem to find anything.

Client side I am receiving this very generic error:

```
Wed Dec 21 16:26:17 2016 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Wed Dec 21 16:26:17 2016 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

Server side is more verbose. Currently I am getting the following error:

```
2016-12-21 13:19:38-0800 [-] OVPN 10 OUT: 'Wed Dec 21 21:19:38 2016 Authenticate/Decrypt packet error: packet HMAC authentication failed'
2016-12-21 13:19:38-0800 [-] OVPN 10 OUT: 'Wed Dec 21 21:19:38 2016 TLS Error: incoming packet authentication failed from [AF_INET]<client public IP>:63413'
```

To configure the server, I used this: https://github.com/pl48415/openvpn-install-advanced

The script has worked fine for me in the past (also on 14.04 systems). Only this particular server is causing issues.

Interestingly, disabling tls-auth (both server and client side) as suggested by many other posters will only yield this error:

```
2016-12-21 12:22:47-0800 [-] OVPN 10 OUT: 'Wed Dec 21 20:22:47 2016 TLS Error: cannot locate HMAC in incoming packet from [AF_INET]<client public IP>:56375'
```

The following are my config files:

```
client
dev tun
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
proto udp
remote [DDNS Domain] 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
tls-client
comp-lzo
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[Redacted]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
[Redacted]
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[Redacted]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
[Redacted]
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
key-direction 1
<tls-auth>
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
[Redacted - Identical to server key.]
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
```

--

```
local 192.168.1.2
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
push "register-dns"
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/ta.key 0
mode server
tls-server
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/crl.pem
client-to-client
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Well, obvious sanity check: use tcpdump on both sides to confirm that your packets are indeed arriving intact.

Comment: Are you using network manager to setup your client ?
It seems couple of people have experienced the issue see below:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/594868/openvpn-hmac-authentication-failure-no-matter-what-i-do Hope that help. Matth

Comment: Everything seems to be in order here.